# Publish/install a gmail addon for specific users don't belong to my domain

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace

I want to create and publish/install a gsuite gmail for the customers work with my company.
Google Workspace just allows to publish an add-on on privately for the user on my domain or publicly for any user can use it. So do we have any way to let some specific users can install and use my add-on on gmail?

Comment: You could just give them the raw code and let them install it themselves on their system.

Comment: Can I export it like a package and send it to my customer? Let them access to project code is quite complicated for them and they can see all source code. Thanks.